# How to create a top-level servlet in liferay

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, liferay-6

I wanted to create a servlet in liferay that is listening to a URL such as

```
http://localhost:8080/my-servlet
```

I tried to add it to a portlet but the I have the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/my-portlet/my-servlet
```

I tried to add my servlet description to the web.xml of ext-web, but no luck.
Is there any way to add such a servlet ?

Comment: Cant you create web project and deploy on liferay tomcat?

Comment: Will this be top-level or will it prefix the url with it´s own name ?

Comment: It will be prefix with project name

Comment: yea, thanks for your answer but I really want it to be top-level.

Comment: Follow this sample to learn how to create a servlet path in a liferay plugin: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/hooks/sample-servlet-filter-hook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Liferay is also "Servlet"-Application - but a very-very big one. And Liferay need some servlet container like tomcat, jetty, jboss etc.

However, you can simple create servlet project and deploy it direct to servlet container where liferay is running.

edit: and put to web.xml by servlet-mapping a direct access like "/*".

Comment: That´s true. Sometimes the solutions are really simple: portal-service.jar can still be used ... :)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to access Liferay service API, you may consider using PortalDelegateServlet : adding the following to your web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>servlet-class</param-name>
        <param-value>org.example.MyServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sub-context</param-name>
        <param-value>myservlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

will make your servelt accessible through

http://example.org/delegate/myservlet

in your servlet class, you then do things like extract the logged-in user and check permissions:

```
package org.example;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);
    PermissionChecker permissionChecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(user);
    ...
```

Comment: sounds fantastic ! Thanks for the hint

Comment: how to prevent "not found page" when access to url??