# How to get PortletRequest in the JSON WebService in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

This question originates due to I need to use *LoginUtil.login()* in my Liferay portlet. Well, to affect the login method from *LoginUtil* I should have *HttpServletRequest*, *PortletRequest* or something similar.

Could you explain me how I can get these objects in the JSON WS layer? Or probably there are another ways to practice digest authentication in Liferay 6.2?

Answer (score 1):

The Web Services layer in Liferay is actually quite separate from the request handling for Service Builder-generated REST calls.  Liferay provides you with some information in the `XXXServiceImpl` class, notably the user information through `this.getUser()`, but you will not be able to access the actual HTTP request from here.  If you need the raw request and have control over the URL you are calling, I would recommend creating a servlet (see Alain Dreese's comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950689/how-to-create-a-top-level-servlet-in-liferay)).

Comment: I just need to get access to the login method from LoginUtil. Unfortunately,  i can't use default login portlet , and i want to use my custom portlet for perfoming logging. I tried to get access from service () method in the new servlet but i got classnot defined error or so. Probably you know way to do it? Thanks for attention.