# Creating a secure Liferay Servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, extjs, liferay

I'd like to develop a servlet whichs works as a datalayer between a porlet written in JavaScript (ExtJS) and a database.

Thus I downloaded Eclipse JavaEE and created a sample servlet project. I also successfully deployed a servlet which receives a http-get-request, calls the DB and outputs the result.

But everyone who nows the servlet-uri can call it and sees the result. Thats where it gets tricky - how do I secure my servlet so that only a authenticated/logged in user can call my servlet or how can my servlet check wether the requester is a valid user?

There is a similar question about that Topic but I'm not sure if this is about the same problem: [How to create a top-level servlet in liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950689/how-to-create-a-top-level-servlet-in-liferay)

Unfortunately I have no clue how to get the liferay-libraries (e.g. PortalUtil) into my servlet-project. How do I do this step by step?

Is this concept even a good way to secure the datalayer or are there better options?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Any particular reason why you're writing a *servlet* for Liferay instead of a *portlet*? If you want to utilize the identity management of a portal, you should use the portal infrastructure, which you get in a portlet.

Comment: Because we do have an ExtJS-Application which we can not modify. We only know the input and output this application expects.